# Overflow exception when reading data from memory

Tags: c#, winforms, memory

I'm reading data from the memory using a combination of the process base address + base pointer + offsets. So far, it works as intented for 4 out of 5 cases.

My 5:th try throws the exception below. Is it because of the `address` argument value?

> OverflowExceptption: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

```
public static int ReadInt(long address)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
    ReadProcessMemory(PHandle, (UIntPtr)address, buffer, 
                     (UIntPtr)4, IntPtr.Zero);

    //(UIntPtr)address: -1482250587

    return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is because of the *address* value.  It cannot be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is failing because your value of `address` is negative.

Which process base address + base pointer + offsets gives this value?